# Xcode changing my xib when opening another file

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview

This is what is happening:

I Have a NSTableView in a xib that uses a custom view for cells. This works fine if I press run when the xib is open.

However, when I leave the xib and run with any other file open the XCode changes my xib. I have commited the working xib, changed file and this is what xcode is changing:

```
 <imageView horizontalHuggingPriority="251" 
            verticalHuggingPriority="251" 
            id="Ciy-iY-YFr">

[REMOVED]<rect key="frame" x="20" y="5" width="50" height="50"/>
[ADDED]<rect key="frame" x="20" y="-56" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Basicly it changes my imageView that is inside the cell. I have tried to remove auto-layout, create again the tableView and nothing worked so far :/.

This is happening on XCode 5.0.3 on OSX 10.8.

Comment: Could you try to set the frame of the imageView on code?

Comment: That is cheating :p. And yes, it works. And yes, I was so obsessed to figure this out that I didn't think in that simple solution. Although I would like to understand what is happening here "under the hood". I wish I could give you points for that comment though :p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand something: just because you are seeing a given `frame` on the `UIView's` subclass, it doesn't mean it will be there when the code gets run. If you are using auto-layout most probably you have "orange" lines on the Nib file, which means that you have some inconsistencies between the view's frame and the actual auto-layout constrain. So

1. Check if you have inconsistencies (orange line. Blue is good!).
2. Disable auto-layout and check if you have some weird auto-sizing mask. Which can affect your view's frames.
3. If none works, go with code. :)